# Stopping an unstoppable service

Tags: windows-vista, services

I have antivirus service (Kaspersky) that occasionally becomes unresponsive to the normal stop/stop gui interface provided by said vendor. I would like to find a way to kill the service for a restart without rebooting, however all attempts I have tried result in failure with an 'Access is Denied' error. These include:

- Services Control Panel (grayed out stop button)
- Task Manager
- Killing Process Explorer Killing
- command line net and sc stopping
- runas with domain admin using net stop

Some details include:

- Machine: Windows Vista
- Service Type: `10 WIN32_OWN_PROCESS`
- Service State: `4 Running (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)`

Answer (score 3):

@richard states:

> If Process Explorer is unable to kill the process ... then it is really unkillable.

Not correct, there are certain processes I couldn't kill with Process Explorer but with other tools like rootkitunhooker.exe.

Also Process Explorer does not show RootKit processes, so it also can not kill them.

I usually use the "psexec -s" approach.

pskill.exe may not work within psexec -s, but I have described a [workaround](http://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/WorkAroundSysinternalsLicenseP.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

If Process Explorer is unable to kill the process when running as administrator (this is important, non-admins can only kill their own processes), then it is really unkillable (Process Explorer will use all methods including debug APIs).

As an AV system it seems likely that it is unkillable because threads are blocked in the kernel (these have to return before they and their process can be terminated).

This is probably a problem in Kaspersky's driver mode code, check with them for updated software or consider a different anti-malware solution.

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky is protecting itself from viruses like this.

Go into the settings of Kaspersky and remove the check at a setting, which is called somewhat like "Protect service from closing".
I don't know the exact phrase, because I use the german UI.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be found in [supershell](http://p-nand-q.com/download/supershell.html), or the later [grootshell](http://p-nand-q.com/gtools/grootshell.html) from the same site:

> A rootshell for nt/2k/xp. Well,
>   actually a shell that runs in the
>   security context of the **NT SYSTEM/AUTHORITY**, which means the user
>   has ie. the right to use task manager
>   to kill running services. Yipee! Idea
>   originally from some MS sample
>   sourcecode from the MSDN, NT only,
>   adapted to work on both 2000 and XP.
>   Whole lotta fun!
>
> **Note:** You already need administrative
>   (ie. debug) privileges to run it. The
>   whole point is that you run a shell in
>   the security context of the NT
>   SYSTEM/AUTHORITY (the context a System
>   service sees) not the context of an
>   Administrator with GUI login. If that
>   doesn't make sense to you, don't use
>   supershell.

Comment: "psexec -s" will run any process (including cmd or PowerShell) as a system process, and has existed for years. This saves learning a new shell.

Comment: @Richard: absolutely right. Why don't you put it up as an answer?